# Training and evaluating spaCy model by sentences or paragraphs

Tags: nlp, training-data, spacy

### Observation:

Paragraph: `I love apple. I eat one banana a day`
Sentence: `I love apple.`, `I eat one banana a day`
There are two sentences in this paragraph, `I love apple` and `I eat one banana a day`. If I put the whole paragraph into spaCy, it'll recognize only one entity, for example, `apple`, but if I put the sentences in paragraph one by one, spaCy can recognize two entities, `apple` and `banana`.(**This is just an example to show my point, the actual recognition result could be different**)

### Situation:

After having trained a model by myself, I want to evaluate the recognizing accuracy of my model, there are two ways to pass the text into the spaCy model:
1. split the paragraph into sentences and pass the sentence one by one    
`for sentence in paragraph:
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    # retrieve the parsing result`

2. pass the paragraph at once

  `doc = nlp(paragraph)
  # retrieve the parsing result`

### Question:

1. I'm wondering which way would be better to test the performance of the model? Since I'm sure passing by sentence can always recognize more entities than passing by paragraph.
2. If the second one is better, do I also need to change the way that I trained the model? Currently, I train the spacy model sentence by sentence rather than a paragraph.

### The goal of my project:

After getting a document, recognize all the entities that I'm interested in the document.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused with the documentation with spaCy and what I get from it. In the documentation, it says that the library should perform equally well with short or long documents, which is contradictory with my observation

Comment: Just get replay from spaCy author `Matthew Honnibal`, here is the [github link](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1344#issuecomment-331026513)

Comment: hi! I have the same problem with my model. It gives me different results when feeding a whole text or sentence by sentence. So I'm not sure what is the best way of training it. I'm interested to know if you solved your question. I left a question on Spacy forum but haven't received a response.